# What does mean both the operators * and (*) in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I just introduced myself to the Ruby splat oprator. And I played with it lot's of way. but the below experiment somehow made me
think about it twice :)

```
langs = ["java", "csharp", "ruby", "haskell" ]
# => ["java", "csharp", "ruby", "haskell"]

 l1,*,l2 = *langs
# => ["java", "csharp", "ruby", "haskell"]
 l1
# => "java"
 l2
# => "haskell"

 l1,*,*,l2 = *langs
SyntaxError: (irb):27: syntax error, unexpected tSTAR
l1,*,*,l2 = *langs
      ^
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Yes, the error is obvious, as I used more then 1 `*(splat)` operators in the same argument list.

Now I tried to play with it.

```
l1,(*),(*),l2 = *langs
# => ["java", "csharp", "ruby", "haskell"]
```

Ahh! here it works. But couldn't understand why so?

```
 l1
# => "java"
 l2
# => "haskell"
 l1,(*),l2 = *langs
# => ["java", "csharp", "ruby", "haskell"]
 l1
# => "java"
 l2
# => "ruby"
```

From the above example it seems that it is doing skipping of array elements.

***Questions are :***

- (a) what the operator (*) is called?
- (b) when I used in splat(*) in the line `l1,*,l2 = *langs` it consumes all the elements - `"csharp", "ruby"`. Is there any way to see what `*` consumes there technically? Obviously I am teling with the use if `l1,*,l2 = *langs` not by `l1,l*,l2 = *langs`.

Comment: A very well put together question. I don't know anything about ruby, but on the surface it appears to be somewhat of a 'wildcard' array accessor, if that makes sense. I'd assume it consumes as many elements as it can before the next token is parsed.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Thank you to show your interest. I am aware of the `*` but not with (*). :)

Comment: Could anyone suggest me when all answers are **OK** , then what to do? as I can't accept more than one.

Comment: generally speaking, you accept the one which was posted first.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Thanks for the suggestion. I am done :) But guys all you are excellent. At-least I am pleased with your answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is due to [how parentheses work with parallel assignment](http://books.google.com/books?id=jcUbTcr5XWwC&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99#v=onepage&q&f=false) as explained by Matz.

For example:

```
a, b, c = *[1, 2, 3]
a => 1
b => 2
c => 3
```

Is different than:

```
a, (b, c) = *[1, 2, 3]
a => 1
b => 2
c => nil
```

Basically, the parenthesis say: assign the right hand element *at this index* to the variables in the parens.  So 2 is assigned to `b`, with nothing left at index `1` to assign to `c`.  Similarly, (*) will take only the element at the given index and distribute it.

```
# the * is interpreted to mean 'take all remaining elements'
a, * = 1, 2, 3, 4

# the * is interpreted to mean 'take all remaining elements except
# the last element'
a, *, c = 1, 2, 3, 4

# incorrect syntax, can't splat more than once on all remaining
# elements
a, *, *, c = 1, 2, 3, 4

# the * is interpreted to mean 'take all elements at index 1'
a, (*), c = 1, 2, 3, 4

# the *'s are interpreted to mean 'take all elements at index 1,
# then again at index 2'
a, (*), (*), c = 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Typically, the `*` operator is used in conjuction with a variable as `*foo` - but if not it will hold its place and take element assignments as if it were a variable (essentially discarding them)

Comment: Humm, I know it is parallel assignment. But how `*` works without any object or variable post to it. What is `(*)`?

Comment: The splat operator is the same with or without the parenthesis. The () tells ruby to pick out a single element from the right hand side and assign it to the parentheses contents. When * is used on the left hand side of an assignment without a variable, it's simply a placeholder to shift assignment to following elements without actually assigning the 'splatted' element(s) to a variable.  So, no, you can't tell after the fact what was assigned to `*` or `(*)` since you aren't persisting it anywhere, but rather using it as a placeholder.

Comment: `a,*b,c = [1,2,3,4]` => `a=1; b=[2,3]; c=4`. Without a variable with the splat, it simply soaks up the values and discards them. `a,*,c = [1,2,3,4]` => `a=1; c=4`

Comment: @AlexWayne I believe he understand the splat operator, but not why `a,*,*,c` and `a,(*),(*),c` behave differently from each other

Comment: @AlexWayne: I'm not sure what you are trying to ask/explain - please elaborate...

Comment: @PinnyM sorry, my comment was for clarification to the asker, your answer is entirely correct. I just figured the "no-variable" splat case needed to be clarified a bit :)

Comment: @nzifnab Apparently the asker does not, because they ask "But how `*` works without any object or variable post to it?" That was the clarification I was trying to explain.

Comment: @nzifnab Yes you caught my point well. ` but not why a,*,*,c and a,(*),(*),c behave differently from each other` .

Comment: @AlexWayne your explanation also exactly what I meant to say. :(

Comment: @PinnyM you cleared my pain 70% at-least the concept of `(*)` and `*` too. But any chance to get to see the what `*` consumed without any prefix to it means without any `*a` like that syntax?

Comment: @user2060534: If you need it, why are you using `*` without a variable :)?

Comment: @PinnyM to see if Ruby has any tool to access it. as many case for other cases Ruby gives us some tools like `object_id`,`ref2_id()` etc. :D

Comment: @user2060534: unfortunately, no such tool for this

Comment: @WayneConrad, will add `descrollbarify` to my lexicon - thanks!

Comment: @PinnmyM I remain, Sir, your most obedient and humble servant.

Answer (score 6):

Think of it this way:  The parenthesis by themselves (ignoring a variable name or splat operator) are accessing a single element from the array:

```
l1,  (), (), l2 = *['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
 ^   ^   ^   ^
'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'
```

If it were an array of arrays, it would make more sense to use parenthesis:

```
>> l1,(l3, l4),(l5, l6),l2 = *['a', ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], 'f']
=> ["a", ["b", "c"], ["d", "e"], "f"]
>> l1
=> "a"
>> l3
=> "b"
>> l4
=> "c"
>> l5
=> "d"
>> l6
=> "e"
>> l2
=> "f"
```

Therefore the (*) is taking a single element from the array, and splat-assigning it.  The parenthesis themselves take a SINGLE element, the splat then takes that single element and "splats" it.

It's good to note that when performing multi-variable assignment from an array, the splat is not necessary on the array side:

```
>> a,b,c = ['a', 'b', 'c']
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
>> a
=> "a"
>> b
=> "b"
>> c
=> "c"
```

Comment: Couldn't understand ` the splat then takes that single element and "splats" it.` . Where the splat operator in your example? Are you talking about the right hand side one?

Comment: My example didn't have a splat operator because I didn't feel it needed one to illustrate the point.  The *parenthesis* takes the single element 'b' from the first example, or `['b', 'c']` from the second.  A splat inside those parenthesis (instead of variables) would then operate exclusively on that `b` or `['b', 'c']` -- NOT on any part of the rest of the array.

Answer (score 6):

`(*)` really just reads *one* element from the right side. Consider this example, which has a fifth element in the `langs` array:

```
langs = ["java", "csharp", "ruby", "haskell", "python" ]
```

So when you use a normal splat, you get:

```
l1,*,l2 = langs

l1 #=> "java"
l2 #=> "python"
```

in contrast to your example with the parentheses:

```
l1,(*),(*),l2 = langs

l1 #=> "java"
l2 #=> "haskell"
```

I want to mention though, that for this case you would normally use `_` to assign the middle values to "nothing" (equivalent to the last example):

```
l1,_,_,l2 = langs

l1 #=> "java"
l2 #=> "haskell"
```

If you want to see what ended up being inside of the middle values, you can explicitly assign the values to variables like so:

```
l1,*m,l2 = *langs

l1 #=> "java"
l2 #=> "python"
m  #=> ["csharp","ruby","haskell"]
```

or with the other example:

```
l1,(*m1),(*m2),l2 = langs

l1 #=> "java"
l2 #=> "haskell"
m1 #=> ["csharp"]
m2 #=> ["ruby"]
```

So i hope this makes clear that `(*)` isnt an operator on its own, but really just a splat inside parentheses and therefore has no own name.

Comment: one point here - `*` consumes all the rest from the right side. That's good. But where it keeps them after consuming? with `*a` - we can get those values, but with out such post variable - any-chance to get access those rest values? After-all one thing is true that it has consumed them, then **where are they**? :D

Comment: Beware – the splat is very greedy and always hungry. No one has ever seen a value come back from it!